# r-mysql: use r variable to fetch a column from database

Tags: mysql, r

Can I pass an r variable into a function for selecting a column from the database so that different columns are selected every time the variable in r changes:

```
father <- 'father'
myfun(father)
```

Function:

```
myfun <- function (parent)
{
query <-  paste("SELECT '$parent' from table1 where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dob) 
between '",date1,"' and '",date2,"'",sep='')

connect1 <<- dbGetQuery (con, query )
connect1
}
```

Comment: @mt1022 We would also need to make sure that there are spaces between `SELECT` and `parent`.  So maybe make the separator a single space.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and Prasinus, sorry I did not notice that the default sep was changed. Just copied it from OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have a table column be a parameter in a prepared statement.  But I don't see anything stopping you from trying something along the lines of the following:

```
parent <- "father"
query <- paste0("SELECT ", parent, " FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(dob) BETWEEN '", date1, "' AND '", date2, "'", sep='')
```